# get number of comments of facebook comments plugin

Tags: php, facebook, comments

I have *view.php* and *index.php*.
I implemented fb comment plugin in *view.php* and I want to display number of comments on *index.php*

This is how I am displaying comment box dynamically in view.php

```
<div class="fb-comments"colorscheme="light"
data-href="http://www.example.com/'.$product["id"].'"
data-width="100%" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

This is what I have in header of view.php

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

How can I display number of comments on index.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Comments Count](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#counter) plugin will help you out!

Follow the docs, and you'll have a comment count after each post. Remember to include the Facebook code you've got in the `view.php` header on `index.php` too!